# Show ObservableCollection items in CommandLineTool

Tags: c#, mvvm, command-line, observablecollection

I have a class library called something.mvvm there are some classes and folders.

Previously it was used for an mvvm project with an UI.

Now I've added an CommandLineProject. And in the CommandLineProject I want to use the functions from the class library.
In the class library is a function which gets user and set them to an observablecollection.

Now I want to display the users in the console instead of de View(like before).

So my question is, how can I use an observableCollection in a CommandLineTool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Wikipedia: [Console application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Console_application)

*A console application is a computer program designed to be used via a text-only computer interface*

You can't show any graphic elements in a console application. 
If you want to show e.g. all items in your `ObservableCollection` you can loop through the collection and via `Console.WriteLine` you can print your items.

Something like

```
foreach(var item in MyObservableCollection)
{
    var text = <build your string from the properties you want to show>;
    Console.WriteLine(text);
}
```